# Mininet: Pingall using Python API in the CLI

Tags: python, network-programming, mininet

I work on a project where I am given a `mininet` network with some specified hosts and switches. My task is to generate traffic. I am using the commands `ping, iperf e.t.c` on the CLI for this; but I want to create an end solution which will be a script with many of these commands in a sequence to create a lot and random traffic.

I have used scripts so far in the CLI but I am thinking of using the `Mininet`'s Python API in order to make more complicated procedures. My question is, how to specify in the python script to run a `pingall` command on the network via the existing network's CLI.

For instance in the CLI could be: `python script.py net`(where `net` is the network reference given and the python script could do a `net.pingall`, how would something like this work?)

*All the examples Python scripts I have found so far are creating a network but do not take a network as a reference. Sorry, if I miss something obvious I am new to networking. Many thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the Mininet API [here](http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1net_1_1Mininet.html#a4d979e7bbfbee700abd18b4372884f3c) and [here](https://github.com/mininet/mininet) for information and examples as to how run Mininet using Python.

For your question you simply use `net.pingAll` (A is capital).